# Why does my ActionMailer text.erb view file render incorrectly when testing? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm sure this is something easy but at the moment I can't tell what's wrong with one of my mailer tests.

I have this basic test that I am running.

```
test "email should be sent when a post is created" do
  email = PostNotifier.post_creation_notification(@post)
  assert_equal [@user.email], email.to
  assert_equal "ohlohadmins@blackducksoftware.com", email[:from].value
  assert_equal "Post successfully created", email.subject
  assert_match /Hello #{@user.name}, your post has been successfully created for #{@post.topic.title}/, email.body.encoded
end
```

Here is my text.erb file:

```
Hello <%= @user.name =>, your post has been successfully created for <%= @post.topic.title =>.
```

This is the error I receive when I run my test:

[image]

As you can see my variables are not formatting. Why are they not formatting? I've been following Agile Web Development 4 as a reference and this setup I have is similar to what is in the book.

I've also tried to wrap the varaibles in the text.erb file in curly braces like so. `"#{@user.name}` etc. and it still doesn't work. This is annoying. Any ideas? Another set of eyes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think there is issue with erb syntax so have u tried and wpraped variable like in following *<%= @user.name ℅>*.

Comment: That did the trick Amit Sharma. I knew it was something small. It was the %> at the end. Instead of => it needed to be %>. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace ur **text.erb** file with following.

`Hello <%= @user.name %>, your post has been successfully created for <%= @post.topic.title %>.`

i think this will help